# how to choose covariates for multiple regression?

Tags: regression

How does one choose covariates/control variables for multiple regression? I am running two multiple regressions, one with DV of chronic pain and one with negative affect. I chose gender and income based on previous research related to these variables influencing chronic pain and negative affect. However, when I ran one-way ANOVA, income has some significant group differences across my study variables, but on independent sample t-tests, gender does not across my study variables. Is this at all related to how you choose covariates, whether there are significant group differences?

Further, age was correlated with negative affect, but not pain severity, so I wasn't sure if I should enter that one in as a covariate for one of the multiple regressions (with DV of negative affect) but not for the one with pain severity (I wasn't sure if covariates had to be the same for all multiple regression analyses).

Comment: What is your goal? The first thing you need to think about is to define the question you want to answer. Do you want to describe? Do you want to  predict? Do you want to make causal claims?